# Check if exception is handled on higher level

Tags: c#, .net, exception

Is there a way to check if exception is handled on a higher application level to skip logging and re-throw? Like this, for example:

```
        try
        {
            // Execute some code
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if(!ExceptionIsHandled())
                LogError(e);
            throw e;
        }
```

Comment: You mean, can you preemptively check if the calling method somehow catches/handles the exception? I wouldn't count on it. EDIT: and you really should use `throw;` (not `throw e;`). Usually I just have error handling/logging code at the very highest level (either in the `Main` method or the application's `UnhandledException`-ish event. Let it bubble up.

Comment: You shouldn't `throw e;`; `throw;` is sufficient here.

Comment: Exceptions bubble up until either a.) something handles it or b.) nothing handles it. Once something handles it, that's it. You can rethrow, but that doesn't help your case.

Comment: There should be no need to do this. You can log the exception when you realize it's not being handled by anything.

Comment: The point is, you should leave it to the higher layer instead of logging at every call site.

Comment: I don't think this design really fits in with how exceptions are generally used. Usually you code your exception handlers to look at the exception thrown, and if it can handle it, you take care of business inside the catch {} block. If not, you rethrow it, and let a handler at a higher level take care of.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing that I'm aware of. If you're committed to this design (see note at end), you *could* write a wrapper for an Exception that's some sort of `HandledException` and just make its `InnerException` be the one that was thrown. Then you could make your code look like:

```
    try
    {
        // Execute some code
    }
    catch (HandledException e)
    {
        LogError(e.InnerException);
        // Do something else
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw ;
    }
```

*Here comes the stereotypical Stackoverflow "you're doin it wrong" part of the answer...*

**However**, if you've truly "handled" the exception, it doesn't make a lot of sense to be re-throwing it. Maybe your method should just return a failure result, possibly including the `Exception` as a detail item for what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This is old, but I do have some input here. There is a design pattern I've used before that does this very well, but does add a little bit of overhead to everything.

Basically, all methods would return a response object (e.g., `Response<T>`). Any exceptions that occur should be wrapped in the response object and returned instead of thrown.

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public T Payload { get; set; }
    public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; } = false;
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public Exception Error { get; set; }

}

public class MyService
{
    public Response<IEnumerable<Customer>> GetCustomers()
    {
        var response = new Response<IEnumerable<Customer>>();
        try
        {
            var customers = new List<Customer>()
            {
                new Customer() { CompanyName = "ABC Co." },
                new Customer() { CompanyName = "ACME" }
            };

            response.Payload = customers;
            response.IsSuccessful = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response.IsSuccessful = false;
            response.Error = e;
            // A friendly message, safe to show to users.
            response.Message = "An error occurred while attempting to retrieve customers.";
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

You can bubble up the exception without rethrowing it, and handle appropriately. You can then add exception catches for more custom user-friendly messages.

I also use a custom base Exception type for any errors that are safe to show the client. This way I can add a generic catch at the controller level to propagate those prepared error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Well no, hasn't got there yet has it. Exceptions bubble up through handlers.
Usual way to go about this.
Is define your own exceptions, then only catch the ones you are going to handle where you are.

Answer (score 0):

If you could be certain that code was wrapped within a specially-designed try-catch block which was written in a language that supports exception filters, it would be possible to determine before or during stack unwinding whether the exception was likely to be caught by that outer block or by an inner one.  The usefulness of this is rather limited, however, especially given the extremely common anti-pattern of code catching and rethrowing exceptions that it knows it's not going to resolve, simply for the purpose of finding out that they occurred.

If your goal is simply to avoid redundant logging, I'd suggest that you should use a logging facility which can deal efficiently with redundancy.  While some people might argue that it's better to have exceptions logged just once at the outer layers, there are advantages to having more logging opportunities.  If an exception occurs within the inner layer and a middle layer swallows it, logging code within the outer layer will never find out about it.  By contrast, if the inner layer starts out by capturing the exception and arranging for it to get logged, then even if the middle layer swallows the exception the fact that it occurred could still get recorded.